# how can we add 'commas' between words and last word with 'AND'

Tags: sql-server

I tried this but not getting expected one:

```
SELECT reverse(STUFF(reverse(@test), CHARINDEX(',', reverse(@test)), 1, ' dna '))
```

The output should be like:

```
Pavan, Phani, Bhanu, Yaswanth, Prasanth and Brahmi
```

Comment: Your code seems to work, as you can see in this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7de8577a3ccba192c0a4d8cc1f7a76aa. You should be more explicit about the problem that you are facing, showing actual sample data, current and desired results.

Comment: i wanted to give the linput like this DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(256) = 'Pavan Phani Bhanu Yaswanth Prasanth Brahmi',when i gave like this,it is not working

Comment: Personally, however, I would suggest that "Englishing" something is a job for the application layer, not the RDBMS, but that's my opinion.

Comment: can i have a query for this?anyone

Comment: You have you, @Kartheek . It's in your question.

Comment: how to add commas then

Answer (score 0):

I think this query works well.

```
declare @Input varchar(256) = 'Pavan Phani Bhanu Yaswanth Prasanth Brahmi'
select replace(replace(reverse(stuff(REVERSE(@Input), charindex(' ', REVERSE(@Input)), 1, ' dna ')), ' ', ', '), ', and,', ' and')
```

Comment: @Kartheek did you see my answer? It works for every words that you put in your input variable but your answer works just with your own example.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
Id int,
Value varchar(100)    
    )

INSERT INTO TEST 
VALUES(1,'RASEL'),
(1,'NEHAN'),
(1,'NAFIZ'),
(1,'NABIL')

SELECT distinct T1.ID 
,Value = REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(STUFF((SELECT ', '+ t2.Value
          FROM TEST t2
          where t1.Id = t2.Id
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '') ), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(STUFF((SELECT ', '+ t2.Value
          FROM TEST t2
          where t1.Id = t2.Id
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, ' '))), 1, 'dna '))

FROM TEST AS T1
```

Output

```
ID  Value
1   RASEL, NEHAN, NAFIZ and NABIL
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for information guys
finally worked on my question and got this answer.

**Note:this is working n thanks for the help!**

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(256) = 'Pavan Phani Bhanu Yaswanth Prasanth Brahmi'
select substring(@Input,1,5)+replicate(',',1)+SUBSTRING(@input,6,7)+replicate(',',1)+
substring(@Input,12,7)+replicate(',',1)+substring(@input,18,10)+replicate(',',1)+substring(@input,27,10)+replicate('and',1) +substring(@input,37,5)
```

Comment: Hey man. My answer works for any list. look at it. I suggest you to look at my answer and try it at least once.